# "argument type mismatch" error when using a generic type for @RequestBody with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics, payload

I'm trying to implement a generic REST controller for Spring MVC:

```java
public abstract class GenericRestController<T extends GenericEntity> {

  protected final GenericService<T> service;

  public GenericRestController(GenericService<T> service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public List<T> list() {
    return service.list();
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public T create(@RequestBody T entity) {
    return service.create(entity);
  }

  // other basic REST methods such as get(), delete(), etc.

}
```

Then, for example an `ArticleRestController`:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/articles", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ArticleRestController extends GenericRestController<Article> {

  @Autowired
  public ArticleRestController(ArticleService articleService) {
    super(articleService);
  }

}
```

Let's say an article only has a `name` field of `String`.

When calling `GET /rest/articles`, I get the list of persisted articles as expected. But when calling `POST /rest/articles {name: "Any Article Name"}`, I catch the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: argument type mismatch

HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.basepackage.web.controllers.rest.ArticleRestController]
Method [public T com.basepackage.web.controllers.rest.support.GenericRestController.create(T)]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap] [value={name=Any Article Name}]
```

When overriding the `create` method in `ArticleRestController`, no exception is thrown anymore:

```java
  @Override
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public Article create(@RequestBody Article article) {
    return articleService.create(article);
  }
```

Any idea why? Could it be that Spring does not manage to resolve the generic type `T` when used as a `@RequestBody`?

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? (As a suggestion, don't try to over genericize.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 4.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: Did you manually register a `Gson` converter?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No. Could my webContext.xml and my pom.xml be helpful?

Comment: Remove Gson from your class path and add Jackson 2. I'm pretty sure Jackson's Converter can do the generic conversion. I'm not as sure for Gson.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You was right, many thanks! I did not think it could be a Gson limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Spring 4.1, a [`GsonHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/GsonHttpMessageConverter.html) is added to the list of `HttpMessageConverter` instances which Spring uses to serialize an object returned from a `@ResponseBody` annotated handler method. This current `GsonHttpMessageConverter` is not sophisticated enough to deserialize generic types. So when it sees a type variable `T`, it does not try to connect the dots with the type argument `Article` in the `extends` clause and instead uses the default `LinkedTreeMap`.

One option is to add Jackson 2 to your classpath. Spring will registers its [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) before the `GsonHttpMessageConverter`. That is, it will attempt to use it first. Jackson's converter is smart enough to perform generic deserialization.